# How to make sure the page doesn't refresh so my csfile in my razor pages doesn't refresh

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, post, razor, razor-pages

I have a project that includes using form post method with buttons. The problem is that it is like a shopping list where each item has 4 chechkboxes and 1 submit "add to cart" when that is pressed it gets in a tabel of purchased items. The problem is that when you press the submit it reloads the page and my Tanks.cshtml.cs file in the Tanks.html gets reloaded so i lose the date inside. So when i add a item to my list it is always gonna be the last one you clicked and not all the ones you clicked. It is in visual studio 2022 ASP.NET core and razor pages.

//cshtml

```
@for (int i = 0; i < @Model.tanks.Count; i++)
{

    if(i == 4)
    {
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <b style="color:white; background-color:#fecb2b; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px; font-size: 30px;">&nbsp; RVS TANKS &nbsp;</b>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
    }

     if(i == 8)
    {
       <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <b style="color:white; background-color:#fecb2b; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px; font-size: 30px;">&nbsp; RVS UCO CADDY &nbsp;</b>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
    }


 <div class="@Model.tanks[i].gallery">
 <div class="card">

  <img src="~/lib/FotosTanks/@Model.tanks[i].afbeelding"  style="width:100%; border-radius: 10px;">
  <h1 style="color:#076044">@Model.tanks[i].soort</h1>
  <p>Afmetingen: LxBxH (cm)<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; @Model.tanks[i].groote</p>


//here starts the problem
 <form method="post">

  <input name="PompEnZuigstang" type="checkbox" /> Met pomp & zuigstang<br />
  <input name="LengteSlang" type="checkbox" /> Lengte slang (m): <br />
  <select class="form-control" name="lengtes" style="width: 190px; color:#076044; margin-left: 18px;" >
            <option>4</option> 
            <option>6</option> 
            <option>8</option> 
            <option>10</option> 
            <option>12</option> 
  </select> 
  <input name="Volumemeter" type="checkbox" /> Mechanische volumemeter<br />
  <input name="Hittebestendig" type="checkbox" /> Hittebestendig (max. 120°C)<br />
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@i">

  <p><button style=" border-radius: 4px;"  onclick = "onPost(); return false" type = "button">Add to Cart</button></p>
  </form>

 </div>
</div> 
}
```

//cshtml.cs

```
public void OnPost()
        {
            idNummer = Convert.ToInt16(Request.Form["id"]);
            optie1 = Request.Form["PompEnZuigstang"];
            optie2 = Request.Form["LengteSlang"];
            Lengte = Request.Form["lengtes"];
            optie3 = Request.Form["Volumemeter"];
            optie4 = Request.Form["Hittebestendig"];

            if (optie1 == "on")
            {
                tanks[idNummer].optie1 = "X";
            }
            else
            {
                tanks[idNummer].optie1 = "";
            }
            if (optie2 == "on")
            {
                tanks[idNummer].optie2 = $"{Lengte}m";  
            }
            else
            {
                tanks[idNummer].optie2 = "";
            }
            if (optie3 == "on")
            {
                tanks[idNummer].optie3 = "X";
            }
            else
            {
                tanks[idNummer].optie3 = "";
            }
            if (optie4 == "on")
            {
                tanks[idNummer].optie4 = "X";
            }
            else
            {
                tanks[idNummer].optie4 = "";
            }

            Test.Add(tanks[idNummer]);

        }
```

I've been looking for a solution for several hours

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to refresh the page,you can use ajax to call OnPost:

```
<button style=" border-radius: 4px;"  onclick = "callAjax()" type = "button">Add to Cart</button></p>
<script>

    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '',
                headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
                data: $("form").serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    ...
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("fail");
                }
            })
    </script>
```